# Wiggle Path Effect in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Hi would love some geometry nodes help. I'm trying to recreate this effect in geometry nodes. Wiggling noise along a path. This was done with the wiggle paths layer effect in After Effects. Any advice is appreciated.

[Video Effect Example Here](https://twitter.com/SouthernShotty/status/1660401225198600193)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

with this node tree

[image]

you will get this:

[image]

As you can see i even added a multiply node before the scale so you can change the "height" of the noise as well.
Of course you could do the same after the scene time node to influence the speed of the animation.
Playing with the scale and other parameters of the noise texture should give you the animation you want.